# how to derive the DC gain of IPS stage?

Tags: amplifier, gain

I am reading Bob Cordell's book,Designing audio power amplifiers. And here is a basic 50-W power amplifier. Q1,Q2 compose a basic IPS circuit.

It shows how to derive the DC gain of IPS part:

> The approximate low-frequency gain of the input stage is the ratio of the net col-
> lector load resistance divided by the total emitter-to-emitter resistance RLTP (which
> includes the intrinsic emitter resistance re′ of Q1 and Q2). With each transistor biased
> at 1 mA, the intrinsic emitter resistance re′ is about 26 Ω each, so the total emitter-to-
> emitter resistance is 52 Ω. If we assume that the β of the following VAS transistor Q4 is
> infinity, the net IPS collector load resistance is just that of R1. The DC gain of the IPS is
> then 1000/52 = 19. In practice the finite β of Q4 reduces this to about 13.7 if we assume
> that the β of Q4 is 100.
> IPS gain ≈ 13.7

[image]
[image]

I am confused about this part.

1. Is \$r_e'\$ the same as \$R_{be}\$?
2. How the DC gain of the IPS is derived？This formation is close to the gain of CE stage, but I am not clear about the derivation process.

Comment: *I am not clear about the derivation process.* Can you do "small signal analysis"? If not, get studying as it is an essential skill for analyzing this type of circuits.  *Is \$r_e'\$ the same as \$R_{be}\$?* Since you have to ask that, the answer to my first question is likely to be "no". \$r_e\$ is a **small signal parameter** while \$R_{be}\$ is **large signal**. You might want to read: https://www.iitg.ac.in/apvajpeyi/ph218/Lec-8.pdf  That's just what I found in a quick search, feel free to learn this from any other source that suits you.

Comment: What is *IPS circuit*? What does I, P and S stand for?

Comment: IPS refers to the differential input stage, which comprises Q1-Q3.So I guess IP refers to 'input',S means stage.

Comment: Thanks for your source. I will revise this part.